# How do I texture the inside of a cylinder in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I have a cylinder in A-Frame with a texture applied to the outside. I want to make this an igloo I can go inside. How do I apply the texture also to the inside of the cylinder?

```
<a-cylinder></a-cylinder>
<a-entity geometry="primitive: cylinder" material="src: #texture"></a-entity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `material.side` to `double` to render on both sides of the mesh. https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/material.html#properties

```
<a-cylinder side="double"></a-cylinder>
<a-entity geometry="primitive: cylinder" material="src: #texture; side: double"></a-entity>
```